# what is the difference between IBE and ABE schemes

Tags: identity-based-encryption, abe

Can somebody explain in simple words. real life example light help and limitations of these schemes etc.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Is it?

Answer (score 3):

With IBE the public key is a public bitstring as your email. A Key-authority issues a secret key that is tied with this public key.The owner of the secret key can only decrypt.

ABE entails more complex access control on decryption operation such as:"Only the owner of the secret key that corresponds to: Area:=Italy AND Age:<30 and Business:=Researcher" can decrypt. The last predicates are called the attributes

Comment: key $\mapsto$ keys $\:$ and $\:$ corresponds $\mapsto$ correspond $\:$ and $\:$ decrypts $\mapsto$ decrypt $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: ABE can be seen as a generalization of IBE: IBE is an ABE with a single attribute namely the ID. In ABE a user is only able to decrypt, if he matches all the specified attribute values.

Comment: Can I tell that IBE works only with single public identifier and ABE supports multiple attributes with relationships (monotonous/non-monotonous) among them? is is right?

Comment: IBE is the singleton of ABE.